# Логика индексов

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  .......
  f1 NUMBER NOT NULL,
  f2 NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ........
);
```

поле `f1` почти уникально. В таблице может порядка 50 записей с одинаковым `f1` при общем числе записей ~100 000

поле `f2` повторяется очень часто. В таблице не более 10 различных значений `f2`

К этой таблице бывают запросы двух типов

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f1 = :val1 AND f2 = :val2
```

и

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f2 <> 0
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f2 = 0
```

(сравнение идет только с нулем и только на равно/не равно)

Вопрос какой лучше индекс создать

- один составной: `(f2, f1)`
- два простых: `(f1)`, `(f2)`
- составной и простой: `(f1, f2)`, `(f2)`

Comment: С проектированием БД у меня не очень. Но на вскидку кажется так. Первый только по `f1`, так как для первого запроса этого достаточно. Что одну строку достать, что в редких случаях 50 не особо и разницы. Во втором случае, насколько разные значения принимает f2 ? Какой бизнес смысл у этого поля?

Comment: Еще, рекомендую всегда к ораклу ставить метку sql

Comment: Насколько часто планируется добавлять / изменять данные в этой таблице?

Comment: @MaxU в этой таблице будет часто обновляться одно поле (`f3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один индекс, только по `f1`.

Индекс, по которому надо читать существенную часть таблицы - бесполезен. Сильно дешевле обойти всю таблицу целиком последовательным чтением. Планировщик запросов это знает. Как следствие вы можете сделать индекс по `f2`, вы будете тратить ресурсы на его хранение и поддержание актуальности, но он просто не будет использоваться. Или, что тоже гипотетически возможно и что ещё хуже: будет использоваться, но вместо ускорения работы превратит простое последовательное чтение в очень много операций случайного чтения сначала прыгая по индексу, потом по таблице за данными.

Дополнительно отфильтровать некоторые из 50 строк обычно не стоят того, чтобы раздувать размер индекса. Как по хранению на диске, так и в кэше в памяти. Для маленькой таблицы в 100 тыс. записей, впрочем, не принципиально.

---

Если ваша СУБД умеет частичные (`partial`) индексы - то может иметь смысл сделать индекс по `f2` с исключением наиболее частых значений. Вероятно, у вас большинство строк подходят либо под `f2 <> 0` либо под `f2 = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме индекса по `f1`, я бы еще попробовал построить [bitmap index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.html#GUID-B15C4817-7748-456D-9740-8B9628AF9F47) по `f2` и посмотреть какие планы строит оптимизатор. Есть неплохой шанс, что запросы вида:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f2 <> 0
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE f2 = 0
```

будут работать быстрее с использованием `bitmap` индекса по `f2`.

Comment: Я разбил таблицу на две партиции и просто явно указываю в запросе к какой партиции обращаюсь

Comment: @MaxU Пробовал уже. В данном случае (матрица 10х100000)  оптимизатор не берёт индекс, даже с `f2=0`. С тремя возможными значениями всё ок. Где-то видел формулу, как расчитать, когда bitmap индекс будет эффективным, но что-то быстро не нашёл где.